# How to read csv format data from a JavaRDD<String> using StructType Schema in Spark Java

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Using Spark Java, I am trying to read data which has comma separated values in the form of JavaRDD, using a StructType dynamic schema.

I know i can read a json using the below method passing a schema(where schemaStr->StructType and javaRDD->JavaRDD):

```
Dataset<Row> df = spark.read().schema(schemaStr).json(javaRDD);


javaRDD has value as: name1,address11,city111
```

Please suggest how to read a JavaRDD using a StructType schema, as i have comma separated data coming as JavaRDD. And i need to readthe data  using  StructType schema anyhow to convert it to a dataframe as i have a dynamic schema generator utility.

Answer (score 0):

so if I understand correctly, you want to convert `JavaRDD` to `Dataset<Row>`?
If yes, you can create `JavaRDD<Row>` by splitting your `JavaRDD<String>` and pass it to `spark.createDataFrame` with your schema

```
StructType schema = new StructType(new StructField[]{
                new StructField("_1", DataTypes.StringType, false, Metadata.empty()),
                new StructField("_2", DataTypes.StringType, false, Metadata.empty()),
                new StructField("_3", DataTypes.StringType, false, Metadata.empty())
        });

        JavaRDD<String> rdd1 = spark
                .range(5)
                .javaRDD()
                .map(s -> s+",b,c");

        JavaRDD<Row> rdd2 = rdd1.map(s -> s.split(","))
                .map(s -> RowFactory.create((Object[]) s));

        Dataset<Row> df = spark.createDataFrame(rdd2, schema);

        df.show();
```

output:

```
+---+---+---+
| _1| _2| _3|
+---+---+---+
|  0|  b|  c|
|  1|  b|  c|
|  2|  b|  c|
|  3|  b|  c|
|  4|  b|  c|
+---+---+---+
```